# c++ как преобразовать строку вида "abcu1111u2222u3333" в unicode

Tags: c++, строки, utf-8, unicode

Мне на вход передается строка "abcu1111u2222u3333", где "u1111", "u2222" и "u3333" - utf8 символы(там китайский если быть точным).

```
int main()
{
  const char* input = "abсu1111u2222u3333";
  wchar_t* out = ???;
}
```

Как бы его преобразовать? Может, кто сталкивался?

Comment: [std::mbstowcs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/)

Comment: Что такое «юникод», он разный бывает, Вам какой, конкретно?

Comment: Может в строка все же такая `"abс\u1111\u2222\u3333"`?

Comment: @Abyx да, но три подряд символа ведь могут оказаться двухбайтовыми в UTF-8.)

Comment: @Abyx впрочем, вполне вероятно, что автор использует слова Unicode и UTF-8 как синонимы)